# I want to get the current location in Android using GPS

Tags: java, android, gps

Here's the thing. I want to get my current location using GPS. I have done it like the following:

My function to get coordinates:

```
private void obtenerCoordenadas() {
        locationListener = new Course.MyLocationListener();

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 0, locationListener);
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        if (location != null) {
           /* Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Cambio de localización", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            lat.setText("Longitud funcion:" + location.getLongitude());
            lon.setText("Latitud funcion:" + location.getLatitude());
            currentLocation=location;

            textView.setText("Distancia: "+distance);
            previousLocation=currentLocation;*/

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "sin localizacion", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 0, locationListener);
        }


    }
```

and my listener:

```
private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
            if (loc != null) {
                // Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Location changed : Lat: " + loc.getLatitude() + " Lng: " + loc.getLongitude(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               /* Toast.makeText(Prueba.this, "Cambio de localización", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                lat.setText("Longitud onChange:" + loc.getLongitude());
                lon.setText("Latitud onChange:" + loc.getLatitude());*/



                String longitude = "Longitude: " + loc.getLongitude();
                Log.v(TAG, longitude);
                String latitude = "Latitude: " + loc.getLatitude();
                Log.v(TAG, latitude);
                currentLocation=loc;
                distance= (int)currentLocation.distanceTo(previousLocation);
                /*textView.setText("Distancia: "+distance);*/
                previousLocation=currentLocation;
               /* lat.setText("Longitud onChange:" + loc.getLongitude());
                lon.setText("Latitud onChange:" + loc.getLatitude());*/

                /*----------to get City-Name from coordinates ------------- */
                String cityName = null;
                Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(getBaseContext(),
                        Locale.getDefault());
                List<Address> addresses;
                try {
                    addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(loc.getLatitude(), loc
                            .getLongitude(), 1);
                    if (addresses.size() > 0)
                        System.out.println(addresses.get(0).getLocality());
                    cityName = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            /*String s = longitude + "\n" + latitude +
                    "\n\nMy Currrent City is: " + cityName;
            textViewCiudad.setText(s);*/
            } else {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(Course.this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(Course.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // TODO: Consider calling
                    //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                    // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                    //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                    //                                          int[] grantResults)
                    // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                    // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                    return;
                }
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 00, locationListener);

            }


        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }


        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider,
                                    int status, Bundle extras) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    }
```

I want to get the location in my "currentLocation" variable but the problem is that when the function "obtenerCoordenadas" is called, and then I try to do: `currentLocation.getLongitude();` I get this error: `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double android.location.Location.getLongitude()' on a null object reference`

I don't know why that happens.
Any idea?
Thank you.

Comment: Could you add more tags to add more information? What language is this, what framework, if any, are you using? There's a ton of ways to make android apps now so just saying it's an android question isn't specific.

Comment: `NullPointerException`

Comment: Tell me what you need to know. Because I don´t know whatyou need @imad.nyc

Comment: `try to do: currentLocation.getLongitude(); ` ? That is nowhere in your code.

Comment: @LuisDaniels, tags with the language you're using (Javascript, Kotlin, etc..) and framework (flutter, react, bazel) would be a good start. Right now it just looks like Javascript? though I'm not sure, I'm not familiar with Javascript.

Comment: I do it in other part. And there is where I get the message @blackapps

Comment: I´m using java in android studio @imad.nyc

Comment: You should of course post the code that produces the error. It makes no sense to post other code.